# Sorting Arrays in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I am getting an error while trying to sort a simple array... 
The ERROR reads: "use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at file.pl line #"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict
use wardings
use Data::Dumper
my @array
my $array
$array[1]= 5
$array[2]= 2
$array[3]= 3
$array[4]= 4
$array[5]= 1
sub numerically {$a <=> $b}
my @sortedarray = sort numerically @array;

print "@sortedarray\n";
```

I am just trying to sort the array to get:

```
 1 2 3 4 5
```

I am new at perl so this might just be something stupid, but please help me... Thanks

Comment: There are many fine suggestions below. However the *exact* reason for the error cannot be absolutely given due to the given code not being the same as the code generating the warning (see toolic's comment). More effort in question -> better replies (and less down-votes :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays are indexed starting at 0. The error comes from trying to sort the array when `$array[0]` is undefined.

**Update**: Also, in perl, one would write:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my @array = qw(1 2 3 4 5);
sub numerically {$a <=> $b}
my @sortedarray = sort numerically @array;

print "@sortedarray\n";
```

There is no point in declaring `$array` -- that would be a scalar. You are only working with the array `@array`, even though it is called with a `$`. Please read the perl documentation.

Comment: The @array assignment is missing maybe a qw, or perhaps some commas?

Comment: They only start at 0 for the sane -- however, I would stab anyone for making me remember `$[` ... ahh, dammit. Now I need to stab myself.

Comment: @pst: I don't think making the program work through `$[++` would be good for the OP's perl skills :)

Comment: => You can't write `$[++` anymore since `$[` is runtime immutable, assignment to `$[` has to be an integer constant `$[ = 1` and is treated as a file scoped compile time directive.  Now, following pst's lead, I must stab myself.

Answer (score 4):

first of all, you need a semi-colon at the end of every statement.  second, you're not using Data::Dumper, so why do you include it?  You also don't need to declare the sub:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @sorted = sort {$a <=> $b} qw (4 2 3 1 5);
print "@sorted\n";
```

And there we have it.

Comment: @BadFileMagic, no you don't need to declare a sub, but if you are going to sort many things the same way, it can be a nice trick

Comment: @Joel -- I agree in principle, but in simple cases like this were it's a straight comparison having a sub routine with a name longer than the block is a bit of over-kill.

Comment: @Joel: especially since perl will highly optimize `sort {$a<=>$b}` when you don't use a subroutine (also `$b<=>$a`, `$a cmp $b`, and `$b cmp $a`).

Comment: @ysth, I didn't know that! I was coming from a dry/laziness perspective. Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a shedload of semicolons.

It's `warnings`, not `wardings`.

Element `0` in your array is undefined.

Comment: i just quickly type what i had (not copy and paste)...hence wardings. Thanks tho

Comment: Dammit, now I want a "wardings" pragma! Unfortunately, I can't decide quite what it should do... (Disabling black magic like `$[` would be a good start, though. Maybe also prevent the process from becoming a daemon?)